# Can i pass protocol type to generic class

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol A and there are multiple structs conforming to protocol A. I need to store different struct objects in a collection. But my collection type is predefined by another service, which is of type - class Storage<Value:Codable>. I can't pass in Value type as A, and it throws an error saying Protocol A does not conform to type Decodable. I just want to know if this is a right approach passing a custom protocol and can i make a custom protocol conform to Codable Protocol. Sample code snippet.

Any thoughts would be helpful

```
class Storage<Value: Codable>{}

protocol A {}

struct Type1: A, Codable, Equatable, Comparable {}
struct Type2: A, Codable, Equatable, Comparable {}

let storage = Storage<A>() // Throws error - Type 'A' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

Comment: You need to specify that A refines Codable: `protocol A: Codable {}`

Comment: Why do you need to mix different object types in a collection? Show a practical usage. IMO you are going in the wrong direction.

Comment: I agree with @LeoDabus , you should probably use that class as `Storage<Type1>()` and `Storage<Type2>()` instead of with the protocol

Comment: @LeoDabus - I want to store polymorphic models which has similar base type in one single collection. For example: My protocol A is of type Car with common properties and my structs are of different car types with common + unique properties.

Comment: @HariharasudhanDuraisamy So just add a property to differentiate them. Why do you need two different structures if they have the same properties?

Comment: @LeoDabus - So each struct has unique mandatory properties which are not part of protocol. That is the reason why I want to segregate them by unique struct by types. The question I have is how do I enforce user to create struct objects with mandatory fields based on type.

Answer (score 1):

use basic class

```
class Storage<Value: Codable>{}

protocol A {}

class Type: A, Codable {}
class Type1: Type, Equatable, Comparable {}
class Type2: Type, Equatable, Comparable {}

let storage = Storage<Type>()
```